# Magento - Call to a member function loadByIncrementId() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, google-ads-api

I am trying to pass data from Magento to AdWords using snippet of code I found poking around about the issue.

I then take the variable in the code and pass it to my AdWords tracking code. I have blocked out sensitive client information, but the code is still there.

I have placed the code within the body tags on the success.phtml page in Magento, but it is not working and in fact returns an error message that is visible to the user. (not good).

See below:

```
<?php
$order_details = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->getLastRealOrderId());
$adwords_saleamt = $order_details->subtotal;
?>

<!-- Google Code for Website Conversions Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1011076746;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "3B7tCPfZj2YQip2P4gM"; var google_conversion_value = $adwords_saleamt; var google_conversion_currency = "USD"; var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1011076746/?value=$adwords_saleamt&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=3B7tCPfZj2YQip2P4gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

The exact error is Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByIncrementId() on a non-object in (page directory here) on line 67 (line 67 is line 2 in my code, with the rest of the success.phtml code being above those lines).

I have looked into this error message. It appears some part of my code is not being properly instantiated when I run this PHP code, but I'm not sure what.

Any help would be appreciated. Again, this is ADWORDS and MAGENTO not playing nicely together. Please only answer if you have some experience with these two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code seems almost right, but two things I encountered:

- First: Are your quotes correct in `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId();` correct?

  - It seemed your sigle quote signs here `Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)` are not correct single quotes.
- Second is that the Checkout/Session Model `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` has only the method `getLastRealOrder()` *not* `getLastRealOrderId()`

Comment: All good ideas. Question though: how can I test this? The site is in Magento which means I can only render a test of the success.phtml page if I place an order.

Comment: Right, as long as you do not have a Testing environment you probably need to test this placing an order in your live environment.